# How to jump to a specific cell based on the list selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a drop-down list in cell R5 containing names, lets call them Name1 Name2 Name3. I'd like when the user selects a certain name the sheet will scroll down to a specific row. For instance, if Name 1 is selected I'd like it to go to row 2, if Name2 is selected row 10, and Name3 row 18. The list is on the same worksheet as the data I'm wanting to scroll to. Is there some code I can use to do this?

Comment: Probably want a `Worksheet Change` event, where you see if the cell with the dropdown was changed.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, can you tell me what that code would look like?

Comment: @osugirl7 "O-H!"

Comment: @ArcherBird "I-O"!

Comment: Archer, other OSU, Oklahoma State! :D

Comment: @osugirl7 Ooh I guessed it. That's ok, I got you covered.

Comment: thanks @BigBen! It was a 50/50 shot, lol

Comment: @BigBen - her name would be "THEosugirl", if it was Ohio, no? :P

Comment: @BruceWayne hahahahahahahahahahahahahaha, fair point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use Sheet Events to handle this. Something like this:

In your Worksheet Module of the worksheet that has your input range, put this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim InputRange As Excel.Range
    Set InputRange = Me.Range("R5")

    '// Check if the change is happening in your dropdown cell
    If Not Intersect(Target, InputRange) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case InputRange.Value
            Case "Name1"
                Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2
            Case "Name2"
                Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 10
            Case "Name3"
                Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 18
            Case Else
                '//...
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit:

If you're having trouble getting this to work. Try adding a breakpoint by clicking in the area to the left of the code. A breakpoint will halt execution when the flow of code reaches that point. This is one way to figure out if Excel is even TRYING to run this block of code.

[image]

[Debugging Excel Code](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/4/8/debugging-vba-code-adding-breakpoints)

Comment: You'll need to make sure macros are enabled and that this is placed in the correct worksheet module. Sorry, not sure why else it might not work for you.

Comment: my macros are enabled, I know this because I have other macros that are working. Nothing happens when I ran your code.

Comment: My guess is that the ScrollRow is already in view of your window so no scrolling actually happens in that case?

Comment: I thought the same thing so I changed it to rows 30 and 60 and still nothing happens.

Comment: I don't know if it matters but the I created the list using the Data Validation window.

Comment: @osugirl7 hmmm, something seems to be wrong with your event handling. Maybe check to see what is the value of `Application.EnableEvents`?  Make sure it is true. Other than that, try putting a breakpoint at the Sub signature and then changing your R5 cell. See if it even stops on the breakpoint.

Comment: Sounds Greek to me lol, sorry I'm not all that familiar with coding. How do I check the value of Application.EnableEvents and add a breakpoint?

Comment: @osugirl7 added some debugging notes in the answer. Pless `Ctrl+G` to show the Immediate window in your VBEditor. In the Immediate window, you can type `?Application.EnableEvents` to see this value.

Comment: I'm having server issues right now and I can't do anything in excel so I'll try your suggestions later and comment back. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: after resolving some computer/server issues this code now works thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Say we put a little jump table in columns **S** and **T** like:

[image]

The row numbers are in column **T**.  We put the drop-down in **R5** and the following code in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim R5 As Range, v As String, r As Range
    Set R5 = Range("R5")
    If Intersect(Target, R5) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    v = R5.Value
    Set r = Range("S:S").Find(what:=v, After:=Range("S1"))
    Application.Goto Range("A" & r.Offset(0, 1).Value)
End Sub
```

Whenever the user picks a new name in cell **R5**, the code will jump to the row listed in column **T**.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Curious why you use `Application.Goto Range("A" & r.Offset(0, 1).Value)`, instead of say `Range("A" & r.Offset(0, 1).Select`?

Comment: @BruceWayne  I have problems in the past in which the destination was **Selected**, but the sheet did not scroll to the newly selected cell.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this code too and it still doesn't work. My file is macro enabled so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: @osugirl7 - "...still doesn't work" - how doesn't it work? Does nothing happen? Does it do *something*, just not what you expect?  Also make sure this code is in the **worksheet**, not a workbook module.

Comment: @BruceWayne nothing happens. I put the code on the worksheet like you said. Right-click the tab and copy and paste.

Comment: @BruceWayne after resolving some computer/server issues this code now works thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the cell. At bottom of the popped up window you find "Hyperlink". Click it. Another window opens. There select the sheet and enter the cell number where you want to go. That's all. In this cell the address given under hyperlink appears. If you give a name to it that name appears. Thereafter whenever you click on this cell/name in this sheet you go to the cell in the sheet specified under "Hyperlink". You can enter data in the new place. But you won't be able to come back to this cell on pressing enter. When you press "Enter" in the new place you go to the next cell in that sheet as usual. I used another hyperlink to come back. It is working for me. I Hope this is a facility provided by excel for jumping easily to a new location based on the hyperlink. Hope there won't be any cascading effect. I hope this is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: On a review I find your requirement is something else. My answer is if you have data in the cells. Not for an item in the list attached to a cell. The list is for validation. The variants in the list don't have a place on the sheet. The selected one comes to the cell.

Answer (score -1):

Press TAB on your keyboard. It might work. Just try it.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I'm not sure what you mean. When I press tab it just tabs over one cell....

Comment: Kevin you should read the question and answer accordingly. Any random answer won't help anyone.