# Excel jump to a specific column/cell based on a dropdown menu

Tags: excel, vba, dashboard

I'm volunteering in a nursing home and creating easy solutions for the carers better help their residents. I'm working on an an interactive Excel calendar but I need a functionality I've been searching the Internet for, without any success.

I need a solution for my excel (VBA, I'm guessing based on similar questions) that allows the user to select a calendar date from a dropdown list with lots of dates and then the user will jump to the specific cell with that date on another range.

My range with dates is in a single row: F9:UA9 and my dropdown is in B11.

I'd like that by selecting "20/09/2020" on the dropdown, the user would move to the cell in range F9:UA9 where that date first appears.

Here's some sample data.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4GjH.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try anything? How about `Range.Find` or `Application.Match`?

Comment: I don't know any VBA, I've tried improving the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582734/how-to-jump-to-a-specific-cell-based-on-the-list-selection?rq=1 

But since I have no idea how to edit, I didn't get it right... Since there were jumping in the same column and I need to jump horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you linked to has the basic shell of what you need. You can use `Application.Match` to find the first instance of the date, and then `Application.Goto` to scroll to it.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim dropDownRange As Range
    Set dropDownRange = Me.Range("B11")

    '// Check if the change is happening in your dropdown cell
    If Not Intersect(Target, dropDownRange) Is Nothing Then
        Dim lookInRange As Range
        Set lookInRange = Me.Range("F9:UA9")

        Dim matchResult As Variant
        matchResult = Application.Match(CLng(dropDownRange.Value), lookInRange, 0)

        '// First check that the corresponding date was found
        If Not IsError(matchResult) Then
            Application.Goto lookInRange.Cells(matchResult), Scroll:=True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Add this code in the *sheet code module*:
[image]

If you want to scroll to row 1, perhaps the following:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim dropDownRange As Range
    Set dropDownRange = Me.Range("B11")

    '// Check if the change is happening in your dropdown cell
    If Not Intersect(Target, dropDownRange) Is Nothing Then
        Dim lookInRange As Range
        Set lookInRange = Me.Range("F9:UA9")

        Dim matchResult As Variant
        matchResult = Application.Match(CLng(dropDownRange.Value), lookInRange, 0)

        '// First check that the corresponding date was found
        If Not IsError(matchResult) Then
            Dim matchRange As Range
            Set matchRange = lookInRange.Cells(matchResult)

            Application.Goto  Me.Cells(1, matchRange.Column), Scroll:=True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! First of all, i really appreciate that you took the time an effort to come to help me! 
I'm trying to put this into VBA commands but it doesn't seem to be working... 

I open the VBA, clicked on the sheet I'm applying the code and pasted exactly what you put here. Is it just that?

Comment: Yes. If it's not working, I'm guessing it's not finding a match.

Comment: Awww :( 

I was really excited that this could work. 
The drop down on B11 is based on the range in F9:UA9, so they're the exact same values (dates). I've also tried to insert the piece of VBA with Insert > Module and then Save and F5, but when I do F5, no macros appear for me to select. I should be seeing 'Worksheet_Change' here with the ability to run it, right? I kindly request if you could take on last look at the code :)

Comment: Did you put this in the sheet code module? (Right click the sheet > View Code)? If so, the date formatting might be the reason it's not finding a match.

Comment: I tried with putting in the sheet and also in the insert module. I've also tried to check if i it's the date formatting, switching the range to A,b,c,d,e,f, etc... and the dropdown is still not making the cursor jump to the cell with that value :\

Comment: To debug, you could add a `MsgBox "Test"` after `Set dropDownRange = Me.Range("B11")` to see if the event is even firing at all.

Comment: Hello, thanks for following up, I really appreciate!
I placed an enter after the
Set dropDownRange = Me.Range("B11") and then placed the MsgBox "Text". My code in "Modules". I saved it, it's an excel macro enabled file, and I changed the dropdown list to a value and nothing happened :/

Comment: If I press F5 from the VBA code window, all I get is that it opens the Macro window without any macros on it, as if this wasn't getting "stored" somehow

Comment: Try the edited code and see a screenshot of where this code should be entered, namely a sheet code module. This code runs *automatically* and you should not be pressing F5.

Comment: hoooraaayy!!! It's working now for the test sheet. Thanks a lot for your code and patience to follow-up!! It's not working only on the actual sheet I need it and I have no idea why, since everything is similar. edit: I've made a copy of that sheet and now it works. I'm very grateful! Thanks! Is there any way to make it scroll in a way that the first visible row wont be 9 but row 1?

Comment: @GL_99 - see the second code snippet.

Comment: that 2ndcode snippet is giving me a run-time error 13, type mismatch, an error which according to the debugger is in matchResult = Application.Match(CLng(dropDownRange.Value), lookInRange, 0)

Comment: That means that `dropDownRange` doesn't contain a true date, but probably *text-that-looks-like-a-date*, is my guess.